# Specify edition from oracle with flyway

Tags: oracle, flyway

We would like to use the feature of Edition Based Redefinition from Oracle, but we would like to automatize the deployments. I would like to know if it is possible to specify the edition when you connect to an Oracle database with Flyway.

We've been trying with Liquibase, but were no able to do it so far.

Has anyobody been able to do it with Flyway or similar tools?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Flyway, you should be able to make calls to `CREATE EDITION ...` and `ALTER SESSION SET EDITION = ...` from within SQL migrations.

Flyway also lets you specify a piece of SQL that gets called as soon as a connection is opened with the `initSql` parameter - so you could put `ALTER SESSION SET EDITION = ...` there too.